# Dynamic Pricing JS error for Bundled Products

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm running magento 1.4.0.1 and when i create a bundled product with dynamic pricing I get a JS error telling me that the "bundle" object is undefined.

I can see where that var is being declared in the code, but it's not instantiating for some reason.

Is this a known issue?  Is there a fix?

Comment: Switch your theme off and run `default/default`.  Do you still get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the reason for this.  It was a JS plugin that I had installed.  Watchout for third party JS addons, there is some chance it could cause problems with the magento JS.